# Attempt to read property "Categories_name" on null

Tags: laravel-8

I have a problem fetching the Categories_name in the product list.
My database:
category: category_id, Categories_name, Categories_desc
product: id(primary key),product_name,product_desc, image, price,category_id(foreign key),old price.

My web.php

```
Route:: get('/home',function(){
    $products= Product::all();
    return view('home', ['products'=> $products]);
});
```

my product.php

```
protected $fillable = [
        'product_name',
        'product_desc',
        'image',
        'price'
    ];
        protected $attributes=[
            'image'=>' ',

        ];

      public function categories(){
       return $this->belongsTo(Category::class,'category_id');
      }
```

my category.php

```
public function product(){
        return $this->hasmany(Product::class,'category_id');
  }
```

my home.blade.php

```
<div class="product-content">
<h3><a href="product-details.html">{{$product->product_name}}</a></h3>
<div class="product-price">
<span>NPR {{$product->price}}</span>
<div><span>{{$product->category->Categories_name}}</span>
                                                        
</div>
</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you have typo in your code:

```
{{$product->category->Categories_name}}
```

should be:

```
{{$product->categories->Categories_name}}
```

Comment: SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'categories.id' in 'where clause' (SQL: select * from `categories` where `categories`.`id` = 1 limit 1)

Comment: use `protected $primaryKey = 'category_id';` in your category model. It assumes your pk is `id`.

Comment: yw, and don't forget about checking as correct answer :)

Answer (score 0):

Check this,

1. category_id is not in your $fillable array in your products model.
2. Check in your Database if the category_id is inserted in the product table.

Then change this

```
{{$product->category->Categories_name}}
```

To this

```
{{$product->categories->Categories_name}}
```